# What's the difference between と思いきや and と思った

Tags: meaning, conjunctions

What would the difference between と思いきや and と思ったが in the following sentence:

やっと富士山の頂上に着いたと＿＿＿＿＿、まだ８合目だった。

I feel that they can both translate to "I thought~" but I think there's a finer nuance involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> やっと富士山の頂上に着いたと思った、まだ８合目だった。

This would be two distinct sentences, awkwardly connected by a comma. Japanese usually disallows joining two related clauses with no conjunction in the middle. So you have to put something in between.

～と思いきや is an idiom that includes a conjunction (that means you cannot use it without a following clause). It also contains a certain amount of rhetoric, so I think the nuance would be clearer when translated like below rather than literal one.

> やっと富士山の頂上に着いた**と思いきや**、まだ８合目だった。
>   ***I thought** I finally reached the top of Mt. Fuji, **where** it **in fact** is only the 8th station (out of ten).*

It focuses on the moment of a sudden change in situation or realization of one's misconception. The closest alternative to this expression is ～と思ったら.

> やっと富士山の頂上に着いたと思ったら、まだ８合目だった。

Answer (score 2):

[思いきや](https://www.edrdg.org/cgi-bin/wwwjdic/wwwjdic?1MDJ%BB%D7%A4%A4%A4%AD%A4%E4) means "contrary to expectations".

There is also an example on that page:

> あっさり断られると**思いきや**、彼女は承諾してくれました。 I had expected an outright refusal, but to my surprise she agreed.

The other alternative in your question,

> やっと富士山の頂上に着いたと**おもった**、まだ８合目だった。

doesn't sound natural since we would expect something after that, for example

> やっと富士山の頂上に着いたとおもった**のに**、まだ８合目だった。

Comment: Thanks! I actually intended to ask the difference between 思いきゃ and 思ったが but somehow, I missed the particle.

So, if we are to compare 思いきや and おもったのに, would there be a big difference?